# Linq to Entities cycling left outer joins

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have following problem with Linq to entities.

Diagram:
[image]

Linq to entities query (incomplete yet):

```
from a in Anlaesse 
join b in Beurteilung on a.AnlassID equals b.AnlassID into ab 
from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty() 
join r in Rangliste on a.AnlassID equals r.AnlassId 
join p in Pony on r.PonyId equals p.PonyID into rp 
from p in rp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
where a.AnlassID == 67 
select new 
    {         
    BeurteilungId = b.BeurteilungID == null ? 0 : b.BeurteilungID, 
    PonyID = p.PonyID == null ? 0 : p.PonyID, 
    Name = p.Name, 
    PonyName1 = r.PonyName1, 
    AnlassId = a.AnlassID == null ? 0 : a.AnlassID 
    }
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AnlassID] AS [AnlassID], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BeurteilungID] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 
[Extent2].[BeurteilungID] END AS [C1], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[PonyID] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent4].[PonyID] END
AS [C2], 
[Extent4].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent3].[PonyName1] AS [PonyName1] 
FROM    [sspv].[Anlaesse] AS [Extent1] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sspv].[Beurteilung] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AnlassID] 
= [Extent2].[AnlassID] 
INNER JOIN [sspv].[Rangliste] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[AnlassID] = 
[Extent3].[AnlassId] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sspv].[Pony] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[PonyId] =  
[Extent4].[PonyID] 
WHERE 67 = [Extent1].[AnlassID]
```

Problem is that I'm unable to add the left outer join between Pony and Beurteilung because all tables are already "used" in my query. Without this the result is wrong because it Returns for each Pony all Beurteilung.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `where` clause to match the `Pony` to the `Beurteilung`? Without knowing on what you want to join these two entities, it's difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I tried this but it behaves like an innerjoin, thus nothing is returned.
Result schould return all Rangliste with Details from Anlass and Pony (if there exists a Pony and Details about Beurteilung if a Pony exists for the given Anlass and this Pony has a Beurteilung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want to left join `Pony` to `Beurteilung`. And let's assume both have a `PonyId` property. A clause like this would act as an inner join:

```
where p.PonyId == b.PonyId
```

A clause like this would act as a left join.

```
where b == null || p.PonyId == b.PonyId
```

However, you are finding this hard because it really doesn't look like you are using Entity Framework properly. Have you mapped any navigation properties or collections? If you haven't then add them because this is sort of the point of EF. If you have then you shouldn't have any need to use inner or left joins; you just traverse the navigation properties.

Comment: Hi Tim
Thank you for reply. That's it! I didn't know that

    where b == null || p.PonyId == b.PonyId

is interpreted as left outer join from EF. Now it seems to work.
Yes, I know somehow strange design but unfortunately this is a legacy database I have to use without possibility of modifications.

Comment: You don't modify the database to add navigation properties. You modify the Entity Framework context. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx